# error: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I have a java code for a red black tree.

```
public class RedBlackBST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> 

    {
        private Node root;
        private class Node // BST node with color bit (see page 433)
        private boolean isRed(Node h); // See page 433.
        private Node rotateLeft(Node h); // See page 434.
        private Node rotateRight(Node h); // See page 434.
        private void flipColors(Node h); // See page 436.
        private int size(); // See page 398.

        public void put(Key key, Value val){ // Search for key. Update value if found; grow table if new.
            root = put(root, key, val);
            root.color = BLACK;
        }

        private Node put(Node h, Key key, Value val) {
           //inserts the value into the tree
        }
    }
```

Here's my node class:

```
private static final boolean RED = true;
private static final boolean BLACK = false;
private class Node {
    Key key; // key
    Value val; // associated data
    Node left, right; // subtrees
    int N; // # nodes in this subtree
    boolean color; // color of link from
    // parent to this node
    Node(Key key, Value val, int N, boolean color) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
        this.N = N;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

What's weird is that everytime I run it I get an error that says `error: reached end of file while parsing` on the last line of the RedBlackBST code. The problem is I checked and my brackets are closed so it shouldn't be giving me this error but it is so I'm just wondering why it's saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `Node` class is wrong. The `private static final boolean` values should be inside the class and then they must be made accessible from the other class:

```
private class Node {

  public static final boolean RED = true;
  public static final boolean BLACK = false;

  Key key; // key
  Value val; // associated data
  Node left, right; // subtrees
  int N; // # nodes in this subtree
  boolean color; // color of link from
  // parent to this node
  Node(Key key, Value val, int N, boolean color) {
    this.key = key;
    this.val = val;
    this.N = N;
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still giving me the error. It looks like that the private static final boolean values are accessible from the other class yet it keeps giving me the error.

Comment: In the first class, you must explicitly tell that the static variables are in the other class.